# Interface not having requirement to implement methods

Tags: c#, oop

MY main class...

```
[Serializable]
    public class SVO : Operation, IAddSizeAbility, IRemoveSizeAbility
    {
        public SerializableDictionary<string, SerializableDictionary<string, decimal>> Data = new SerializableDictionary<string, SerializableDictionary<string, decimal>>();



        public SVO() //Default Constructor
        {
            SerializableDictionary<string, decimal> line = new SerializableDictionary<string, decimal>();
            line.Add("Size - 0", 0.00M);
            Data.Add("OP - 0", line);

        }

        public void AddSize()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

My interfaces...

```
public interface IAddSizeAbility
    {
        void AddSize();
    }

 public interface IRemoveSizeAbility
    {
        void RemoveSize();
    }
```

The Issue is although I implement the IAddSizeAbility interace correctly I have not implemented the IRemoveSizeAbility but yet it lets me compile is this a bug?

I can't replicate the issue when i create a new set of interfaces classes.

I have included image so you can see there is no red underline under the interface that is not implemented

[image: I have included image so you can see there is no red underline under the interface that is not implemented]

And an image of my test which does what you would expect.
[image: And an image of my test which does what you would expect.]

Comment: Perhaps `Operation` already implements it?

Comment: It's either that or you have more than one `IRemoveSizeAbility` interface in your project.

Comment: @haim770 Yes you are right, can't believe i missed it, post you answer and i will accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare a `class` of certain type as implementing an `interface` and that type inherits from another type that is already implementing the `interface`, the compiler would still be satisfied as the type does not break the contract.

In your case, since `Operation` already implements `IRemoveSizeAbility`, you're good to go.